# How to open a PDF file from server in android

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

I have a requirement where there is a `URL = "http://www.example/Open.pdf"`

Now from my android application I want to open this `PDF` file directly in the default `PDF viewer`.

The moment I click on this link on the `webpage`, user should be presented with a default PDF viewer opened with this document.

Note: This file should not be stored on the `SD card.`

How do I proceed for this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can open a default PDF view from your application.

If your file is on the server and you want to open it without downloading then this might also pose a greater security concern. If external applications like default adobe reader can access the content on your server, then this is breaking the security framework altogether.

So, best option would be to launch a new instance of browser or webview and show the PDF document in google docs to the user.

This way user can read the document and get back to the recent state of the application as well.

Answer (score 2):

We can open PDF file in the webview without caching it. Write below code in `"onCreate"` method .

Working code :

```
    String url = "http://www.example.com/abc.pdf";
    final String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";


    WebView mWebView=new WebView(this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false; // then it is not handled by default action
       }
    });


    mWebView.loadUrl((googleDocsUrl + url));

    setContentView(mWebView);
```

What happens here is you open the PDF using Google Docs. **Best Advantage** of using above method is the **lazy loading of PDF**. Does not matter how heavy the PDF is. Google Docs takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the pdf in the `WebView` using `googleDocs`.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.addView(webView.getZoomControls());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://myurl.com/demo.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks for the post Lalit. But I want it to open in Default PDF viewer like adobe and not in google docs.

Answer (score 1):

> > You can view the pdf in the `WebView` using `googleDocs`.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.addView(webView.getZoomControls());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://myurl.com/demo.pdf");
```

do you have the others solution besides view pdf file using http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://myurl.com/demo.pdf